# how to submit a form to itself by using post method in php?

Tags: php, post

I am trying to submit a form by post method on itself. but every time the form submits and page is refreshed. it doesn't show values.

```
<?php echo $_POST['fname']; ?>
<form method="POST" action='#.php'>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
<button id="check" name="check" type="submit">GO</button>
</form>
```

What's the point, i am missing?

Comment: keep action blank action=""

Comment: One assumes your filename is not `#.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php echo $_POST['fname']; ?>
<form method="POST" action=""> <!-- not single quote -->
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
<input type="submit" name="value" >
</form>
```

Comment: tried, but didn't work

Comment: action = "" not single quote

Comment: @AmanBarnwal, I am getting the whatever I entered in the text box. Can you please give me your full code? On which browser you are executing the script?

Comment: here's a sample page on my desktop 
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php echo $_POST['fname']; ?>
    <form method="POST" action='#.php'>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
    <input type="submit" name="value" >
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: @Aman Barnwal replace the action='#.php' to action = ""

Comment: tried that but still didn't work @dass

Comment: @AmanBarnwal, can you please try to print only <?php echo "Test"; ?> and let me know, it prints "test" or not? Also, run the above code in another browser. Make sure PHP installed on your system.

Comment: it worked, thanks!

Comment: So, the above code is working now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<?php
```

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
```

}
?>

```
<form name="test" action="" method="post"><input type="text" name="firstName" /><input type="submit" name="Submit" /></form>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to write more cleaner way. like this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['fname']) && !empty($_POST['fname']) ){
 echo $_POST['fname'];
}
?>
<form method="POST" action=""> <!-- not single quote -->
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
<input type="submit" name="value" >
</form>
```